# Fill the CheckBox drawable image to CheckBox width in ListView adapter

Tags: android

I have a listView adapter where i set buttonDrawable image in checkbox. I have set the width of checkbox to 1/3rd of the listView.But I can't scale the checkbox drawable image fit to the width of checkbox. I didnt find anything on it

customAdapter

```
@Override
public View getView(final int i, View view, ViewGroup viewGroup) {
    int width = viewGroup.getWidth();
    View rowView;
    rowView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.singlerow_compare, null);
    holder.checkBox = (CheckBox) rowView.findViewById(R.id.imageViewCompare);
    holder.checkBox.setButtonDrawable(imageId[i]);
    holder.checkBox.setWidth(width/3);
}

    holder.checkBox.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
        //I am using this
        }
    });

   //This is not working
   rowView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Log.d("error", "notworking");
            //this is not working so I am using checkbox onclick listener
        }
```

ListView

```
        ListView listView = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.listView);
        customAdapter = new CustomAdapter(this, prgmNameList, prgmImages);
        listView.setAdapter(customAdapter);
```

singlerow.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent" android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:id="@+id/singleRow" android:gravity="center">

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="New Text"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:layout_below="@+id/imageViewCompare"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/imageViewCompare"
        android:layout_alignRight="@+id/imageViewCompare"
        android:id="@+id/textViewCompare" />

    <CheckBox
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/imageViewCompare"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:button="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:focusableInTouchMode="false"/>

</RelativeLayout>
```

[image]

Comment: What is the problem??

Comment: The image size is smaller than checkbox size. I cant scale the checkbox img to fit its width

Comment: share your xml code..!!

Comment: I added the xml and the checkbox image too. the img is drawable img and checkbox has bg color blue. I want to fill the image to the entire checkbox area. ie. cover the bg color

Comment: see my answer below..!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do it like this:

```
 <CheckBox
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/imageViewCompare"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
    android:background="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:button="@null"
    android:focusableInTouchMode="false"/>
```

Instead of setting `android:button` set it in `android:background`

**EDIT 1 :** set

```
android:button="@null"
```

Comment: small check box are also visible if I set it to background. I don't want the checkbox with tick mark. I have set the transparency if the checkbox image is clicked

Answer (score 0):

Use a `Imageview` below `checkbox` and `scaleType` to `centercrop` so that it fits the checkbox

```
    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="New Text"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:layout_below="@+id/imageViewCompare"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/imageViewCompare"
        android:layout_alignRight="@+id/imageViewCompare"
        android:id="@+id/textViewCompare" />

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/imageView"
        android:src="@+id/ic_launcher"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/imageViewCompare"
        android:layout_alignRight="@+id/imageViewCompare"
        android:layout_alignTop="@+id/imageViewCompare"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/imageViewCompare"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:focusableInTouchMode="false"/> 

    <CheckBox
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/imageViewCompare"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:focusableInTouchMode="false"/>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: I didn't use this xml using imageview since I have a problem in row onClickListener. Please hav a look at custom adapter code in the question. thankyou